# Using custom signal handlers with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, signals, gunicorn

I have a Flask application with custom signal handlers to take care of clean up tasks before exiting. When running the application with gunicorn, gunicorn kills the application before it can complete all clean up tasks.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't explain what you mean by custom signal handlers, but I'm not sure that you should be using [Flask's signals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/signals/) to capture process-level events, like shutdown. Instead, you can use the [`signal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) from the standard library to hook onto the SIGTERM signal, like so:

```
# app.py - CREATE THIS FILE
from flask import Flask
from time import sleep, time
import signal
import sys

def create_app():
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, my_teardown_handler)
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/')
  def home():
    return 'hi'

  return app


def my_teardown_handler(signal, frame):
  """Sleeps for 3 seconds, then creates/updates a file named app-log.txt with the timestamp."""
  sleep(3)
  with open('app-log.txt', 'w') as f:
    msg = ''.join(['The time is: ', str(time())])
    f.write(msg)
  sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = create_app()
  app.run(port=8888)


# wsgi.py - CREATE THIS FILE, in same folder as app.py
import os
import sys
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound

from app import create_app
app = DispatcherMiddleware(create_app())
```

Assuming you have a virtual environment with Flask and Gunicorn installed, you should then be able to launch the app with Gunicorn:

```
$ gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8888 --log-level debug wsgi:app
```

Next, in a separate terminal, you can send the TERM signal to your app, like so:

```
$ kill -s TERM [PROCESS ID OF GUNICORN PROCESS / $(ps ax | grep gunicorn | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')]
```

And to observe the results, you should notice that the contents of the `app-log.txt` file get updated when you run that `kill` command, after the three-second delay. You could even spawn a third terminal window in this directory and run `watch -n 1 "cat app-log.txt"` to observe this file being updated in real time, while you cycle between starting the app and sending the TERM signal.

As for tying that into production, I know that [Supervisor has a configuration option](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) to specify the `stopsignal`, like so:

```
[program:my-app]
command = /path/to/gunicorn [RUNTIME FLAGS]
stopsignal = TERM
...
```

But that's a separate topic from the original issue of ensuring that your app's clean up tasks are completely executed.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question. I am using the signal module, however gunicorn shuts down the application before all of my clean up tasks can complete.

Comment: Hmm, how about some info about these clean-up tasks - anything we should know about? Also, how are you running/stopping Gunicorn? And which signal did you attempt to capture?